# Consider defining a bean of type 'org.o7planning.sbshoppingcart.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-bean

When I am running my project,I am getting the error as:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userDetailsService in org.o7planning.sbshoppingcart.config.WebSecurityConfig required a bean of type 'org.o7planning.sbshoppingcart.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.o7planning.sbshoppingcart.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl' in your configuration.
```

I searched for this same error and got some hints to add `@ComponentScan({"com.o7planning"})`.So,I added @ComponentScan in mainclass and this bean error was gone :

When I added this property like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.o7planning"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { //  
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, //
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, //
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })

public class SbHibernateShoppingCart1Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SbHibernateShoppingCart1Application.class, args);
    }
//i have full code down

}
```

But when I run the project then,My spring security configuration is gone and default login form of spring is shown.

[image]

Default login screen is shown,as this needs to override by the login page I provided in spring:

[image]

So,By just adding @ComponentScan my spring security is not functioning.What is the problem?

So,my codes are:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.o7planning</groupId>
    <artifactId>SbHibernateShoppingCart1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SbHibernateShoppingCart</name>
    <description>Shopping Cart + Spring Boot + Hibernate + Thymeleaf</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons Email validator,... -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator%20-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.threeten/threetenbp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
            <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6</version>
        </dependency>    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>



        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

mainclass.java

```
package org.o7planning.sbshoppingcart.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.o7planning"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { //  
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, //
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, //
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })

public class SbHibernateShoppingCart1Application {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SbHibernateShoppingCart1Application.class, args);
    }


    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        // See: application.properties
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));

        System.out.println("## getDataSource: " + dataSource);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        // See: application.properties  
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
        properties.put("current_session_context_class", //
                env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class"));

        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        // Package contain entity classes
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "" });
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        //
        SessionFactory sf = factoryBean.getObject();
        System.out.println("## getSessionFactory: " + sf);
        return sf;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

WebCOnfiguration.java

```
package org.o7planning.sbshoppingcart.config;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        // Load file: validation.properties
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:validation");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
package org.o7planning.sbshoppingcart.config;

import org.o7planning.sbshoppingcart.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Autowired
   UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

   @Bean
   public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
      BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
      return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
   }

   @Autowired
   public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

      // Setting Service to find User in the database.
      // And Setting PassswordEncoder
      auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

   }

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.csrf().disable();

      // Requires login with role ROLE_EMPLOYEE or ROLE_MANAGER.
      // If not, it will redirect to /admin/login.
      http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/orderList", "/admin/order", "/admin/accountInfo")//
            .access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_EMPLOYEE', 'ROLE_MANAGER')");

      // Pages only for MANAGER
      http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/product").access("hasRole('ROLE_MANAGER')");

      // When user login, role XX.
      // But access to the page requires the YY role,
      // An AccessDeniedException will be thrown.
      http.authorizeRequests().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");

      // Configuration for Login Form.
      http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin()//

            //
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check") // Submit URL
            .loginPage("/admin/login")//
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/accountInfo")//
            .failureUrl("/admin/login?error=true")//
            .usernameParameter("userName")//
            .passwordParameter("password")

            // Configuration for the Logout page.
            // (After logout, go to home page)
            .and().logout().logoutUrl("/admin/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/");

   }
}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl.java

```
package org.o7planning.sbshoppingcart.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.o7planning.sbshoppingcart.dao.AccountDAO;
import org.o7planning.sbshoppingcart.entity.Account;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountDAO accountDAO;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Account account = accountDAO.findAccount(username);
        System.out.println("Account= " + account);

        if (account == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " //
                    + username + " was not found in the database");
        }

        // EMPLOYEE,MANAGER,..
        String role = account.getUserRole();

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        // ROLE_EMPLOYEE, ROLE_MANAGER
        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role);

        grantList.add(authority);

        boolean enabled = account.isActive();
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) new User(account.getUserName(), //
                account.getEncrytedPassword(), enabled, accountNonExpired, //
                credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, grantList);

        return userDetails;
    }

}
```

My project structure is:

[image]

Comment: Please share the project structure.

Comment: yes i shared look plz

Comment: IMO you don't need `@ComponentScan` as config and service both are under `org.o7planning.sbshoppingcart` Try to remove it and clean and rebuild project and let me know

Comment: i tried to make new project and copied the same code but the error i saw is: Could not find artifact org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:pom:unknown in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Comment: Add from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4/2.1.2.RELEASE according to version

Answer (score 0):

You have `@ComponentScan({"com.o7planning"})` but your classes are under `org.o7planning` package.

Answer (score 0):

Check your annotation scan package path. maybe becacuse this problem

Comment: This seems to be a comment or suggestions, Better add this kind of suggestions as comments instead of posting this as an answer.